# Smart card reader ACR 38U-CCID not recognizing blank SLE4442 smart card

Tags: macos, smartcard

I'm attempting to use the OpenSC version 0.18.0 library on my Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.5 to communicate with an ACR38U-I1 reader, connected via USB.

Inserting a brand new SLE4428 smart card into the reader, and then executing the following command

```
opensc-tool --reader 0 --atr
```

yields this (obfuscated) output:

```
XX:04:92:XX:10:91
```

The reader is clearly reading information from the card itself.

However, this command to get the name of the card

```
opensc-tool --reader 0 --name
```

yields this output:

```
Unsupported card
```

I have a stack of brand new SLE4428 and SLE4442 cards, and they give the same result.

What configuration changes should I make to correct this issue so `opensc-tool` recognizes either the SLE4428 or SLE4442 cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained an answer from "CardContact" in the OpenSC community that resolves the issue:

"The card is a simple memory card that uses a proprietary communication interface rather than ISO 7816. Those cards are not supported by OpenSC."